# Casued Hibernate by (One-toOne) : org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: referenced property unknown:

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, hibernate-annotations

I'm tried to create one-to-one relationship in hibernate, When I'm implement this relation then I'm getting **org.hibernate.AnnotationException**. Please identify the mistake And Suggest me.

**Vegetable Class**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "Vegetables")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Vegetable implements Serializable  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "P_ID")
    private String productID;

    @Column(name = "Product_Name")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = "Description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "In_Item")
    private LocalDate localDateIn;

    @Column(name = "Out_Item")
    private LocalDate localDateOut;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "vegetable", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Stock stock;
//getter & setter
}
```

**Stock Class**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="STOCK")
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
public class Stock implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer sId;

    @Column(name="stockLevel")
    private Integer stockLevel;

    @Column(name="StockUSed")
    private Integer stockUsed;

    @Column(name="Availablity")
    private Integer availablity;

    @Column(name="OutOfStock")
    private Integer outOfStock;

    //getter & setter
}
```

**Exception**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: com.javabootstar.grofers.domain.Vegetable.stock, referenced property unknown: com.javabootstar.grofers.domain.Stock.vegetable
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not making the correct usage of `mappedBy` attribute in `@OneToOne`. MappedBy attributes communicates that the key for the relationship is on the other side.

In your case it is expecting the vegetable field in your Stock class(which is unavailable), that is why you are facing this exception.

You should use `@JoinColumn` annotation to map foreign key in your Vegetable class

Comment: I wil add @JoinColumn  but same exception will be occur .

Comment: @OneToOne(mappedBy = "vegetable", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "Vegetable_Stock")
 private Stock stock;

Comment: You should not use mappedBy = "vegetable" attribute as there is no vegetable field in your Stock class. Simply using @JoinColumn (with correct values) would suffice

Comment: Okay I will remove it.

Comment: Unknown MappedBy Remove but new Exception raised OneToOne or ManyToOne on com.javabootstar.grofers.domain.Vegetable.stock references an unknown entity: com.javabootstar.grofers.domain.Stock

Comment: Add targetEntity=Stock.class in @OneToOne annotation

Comment: first of follow Thanks you for help @Garima Gupta.